# Quiero darle estilo a la notificación del input cuando el dato no es correcto

Tags: html5, css3

Ya entregué unos estilos al input, pero no sé cómo estilizar esta ventana gris que aparece en el caso de que el email esté incorrecto.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este seria como tengo el html5:

```html
<form class="form">
    <input class="input__email" type="email" placeholder="Enter your email" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9_]+([.][a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9_]+([.][a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*[.][a-zA-Z]{1,5}">
    <button class="btn__started" type="submit">Get Started</button>
</form>
```

No sé si hay que agregar un atributo o que puedo hacer exactamente, lo que quiero hacer es solo con HTML5 y CSS3 sin necesidad de JS

Comment: Me temo que a menos que crees tú un span para el error y controles que se muestre y se oculte cuando haya o no haya error usando javascript, no hay manera de personalizar ese mensaje utilizando solamente html y css. Checa [este ejemplo](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation#un_ejemplo_que_no_usa_la_api_de_validaci%C3%B3n_de_restricciones) con javascript que pone el MDN.

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por la aclaración.

Comment: Inspecciona el elemento y revisa si se puede modificar desde el inspector de código... Podría ser una validación nativa del navegador o una especie de `title` modificado o un `tooltip`.

Comment: Hola, gracias por intentar ayudarme, por el momento lo dejare así y mejor lo hago con JavaScript.